# FireFox 30 Dev Tool Style Editor Formatting Differs From My Own

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

After updated to FF 30.0 I noticed that the style editor in the dev tools is now forcing its own format rather than displaying the stylesheet however I had it formatted in the file myself.

I format my stylesheet so that each rule and all its properties are on one line.  But FF in the style editor appears to display the stylesheet in a line break format for each property of a rule.

I don't see any settings to tell it to display however I formatted the css file, so I'm guessing FF forces this formatting now in the style editor.

Has anyone else noticed this, or am I missing something?  Before FF30 (such as 29) the style editor displayed my stylesheets exactly how they were formatted in each css file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Style Editor thinks that your stylesheet is minified, and so it's prettifying it. The metric for determining when a stylesheet is minified was changed in 30, from a conservative approach to a more aggressive one. Sounds like it needs to be tweaked. Feel free to [file a Style Editor bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Style%20Editor) giving an example stylesheet that you don't want to prettified, or comment here.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into that and see what they say.  It's unfortunate because I spend most of my time in the style editor, editing my css in the format I saved the file in, then copying and pasting it into my actual file to upload.  Back to firebug for now.